# Why does "if return" compile in Rust?

Tags: rust

I found some strange Rust code in dtolnay's mind-bending [Rust quiz](https://dtolnay.github.io/rust-quiz/20). Apparently, this is a valid Rust program ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9a672c0ef5d7ce00bdbf64fb88445cc2)):

```rust
fn main() {
    if return { print!("1") } {}
}
```

According to the [Rust docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/if-expr.html):

> The syntax of an if expression is a condition operand, followed by a consequent block, any number of else if conditions and blocks, and an optional trailing else block. The condition operands **must have the boolean type.**

To me it means that the `return` statement must somehow evaluate as a boolean, otherwise the code wouldn't compile. But that explanation seems outlandish, and I suspect there must be something else going on.

So why does `if return` compile at all?

Comment: The type of a `return` expression is `!`, which coerces to anything (in this case, a boolean).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [never](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html) type, which is the result of the `return` expression.

And while it compiles, it does generate a warning:

```
warning: unreachable block in `if` or `while` expression
  |
2 |     if return { print!("1") } {}
  |        ---------------------- ^^ unreachable block in `if` or `while` expression
  |        |
  |        any code following this expression is unreachable
```

Answer (score 5):

It is for the same reason the following code compiles:

```
fn create_string() -> String {
    std::process::exit(0);
}
```

The body of the function above does never return a `String` value, however, since [`std::process::exit()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/fn.exit.html) is a *divergent function* (i.e., its return type is `!`), it results in valid code: The control flow will never reach the point where a `String` value has to be produced.

The same applies to `panic!()`. The following code, which replaces your `return` with `panic!()`, also compiles for the same reason:

```
fn main() {
    if panic!() { print!("1") } {}
}
```